# Screen space reflections in Blender code

Tags: rendering

I've found the Blender code at https://github.com/blender/blender

I'd like to find the place in the code that implements the screen space reflections.

I've used the search, but I cannot find exactly what I'm looking for.

Any help from those who know the code would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.